# How do I Manually adding Spring MVC import libraries in to a Controller .java file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I created a new Spring MVC Dynamic web project with eclipse. I created a controller class .java file and cut and pasted code from an example project into my new class. Now in the new Controller code I have import libraries in the pasted in code. For example:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
```

Now, how do I go about actually add this import libraries to my project so that they will be included in the Spring MVC application? I am currently using Eclipse to develop the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) for your spring MVC project and add all dependencies to your `pom.xml` , this is easiest way.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been doing ASP .NET and ASP MVC for the past 12 years and I can do anything in Visual Studio. Now I have to learn how to use eclipse and it's much different.